# Difference between GlobalScope and runBlocking when waiting for multiple async

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I have a Kotlin Backend/server API using Ktor, and inside a certain endpoint's service logic I need to concurrently get details for a list of ids and then return it all to the client with the 200 response.

The way I wanted to do it is by using async{} and awaitAll()

However, I can't understand whether I should use runBlocking or GlobalScope.
What is really the difference here?

```
fun getDetails(): List<Detail> {
    val fetched: MutableList<Details> = mutableListOf()

    GlobalScope.launch { --> Option 1
    runBlocking { ---> Option 2
    Dispatchers.IO --> Option 3 (or any other dispatcher ..)

         myIds.map { id ->
             async {
                 val providerDetails = getDetails(id)
                 fetched += providerDetails
             }
         }.awaitAll()
     }
     return fetched
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launch` starts a coroutine that runs in parallel with your current code, so `fetched` would still be empty by the time your `getDetails()` function returns. The coroutine will continue running and mutating the List that you have passed out of the function while the code that retrieved the list already has the reference back and will be using it, so there's a pretty good chance of triggering a ConcurrentModificationException. Basically, this is not a viable solution at all.

`runBlocking` runs a coroutine while blocking the thread that called it. The coroutine will be completely finished before the `return fetched` line, so this will work if you are OK with blocking the calling thread.

Specifying a Dispatcher isn't an alternative to `launch` or `runBlocking`. It is an argument that you can add to either to determine the thread pool used for the coroutine and its children. Since you are doing IO and parallel work, you should probably be using `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO)`.

Your code can be simplified to avoid the extra, unnecessary mutable list:

```
fun getDetails(): List<Detail> = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    myIds.map { id ->
        async {
             getDetails(id)
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

Note that this function will rethrow any exceptions thrown by `getDetails()`.

---

If your project uses coroutines more generally, you probably have higher level coroutines running, in which case this should probably be a suspend function (non-blocking) instead:

```
suspend fun getDetails(): List<Detail> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    myIds.map { id ->
        async {
             getDetails(id)
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative response. 
Small follow up questions : 
1.  Regarding your note of `launch`, I actually at first managed to make it work with 
    `val jobs = myList.map { GlobalScope.launch { fetched += provider.getDetails() } }`
        and then `jobs.joinAll()`. What is the difference between this and async-await? 
2. since it's a REST endpoint, Ktor opens a new IO coroutine(?), so I can use `withContext(IO)`, but is it really like `runBlocking(IO)` in terms of behavior and effect on overall system performance?
3. the parallels are network requests, is IO best for it?

Comment: btw, regarding IO dispatcher, do you think `Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(..)` should be used in use cases like this? if not, what are the guidelines to use limitations on parallelism in your opinion?

Comment: 1. `jobs.joinAll` would have to be called in another coroutine, so I'm not sure how that fits in with your synchronous `getDetails()` function there. Anyway, joining a Job (the type of a launched coroutine) is just like awaiting a Deferred (the type of an async coroutine). The only difference is Deferred produces a value, and a Job doesn't produce anything. 2. I don't know what you mean by "Ktor opens a new IO coroutine". I don't use Ktor, but regardless that phrase doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: 3. Dispatchers.IO is used when you are going to call *blocking* functions that are IO bound. If you are only calling suspend functions, there's no reason to specify a dispatcher at all. I don't use Ktor, but if it's a Kotlin-first library, there are likely suspend functions rather than blocking functions. 4. I haven't personally done any massive parallelism to where I'd have to worry about whether I need to limit it, so I can't provide good advice for that.

Comment: @Tenfour04 can you help me on [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74842209/11560810)